# If else in django template

Tags: python-3.x, django-templates

I have a problem with if/else condition into my template. 
I have a simple form and confirmation button. User should input text in this form, then should press button and only after that, user will see other part of page.

This is my template code:

```
{% extends "home/base.html" %}
{% load staticfiles %}
{{% block body %}

<h1 align="center">Analyzed text</h1>
    <form class="form" action="analyze" method="post">
        <div id="form">
            <dd><textarea id="textarea" name="q" rows=10 cols=55 placeholder=" Input your text in japanese here ..."></textarea>
            <dd><input class="myButton" type="submit" value="Analyze">
        </div>
    </form>
<div class=page>
    {% if 'q' != None %}
        {% include "kanji_analyzer/show_results.html" %}
    {% endif %}

</div>
{% endblock %}}
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from kanji_analyzer.logic_part.kanji_analyzer import KanjiesText


def start_kanji(request):
    return render_to_response('kanji_analyzer/main.html')


def show_entries():
    global analyzed_text
    global list_of_percents
    global list_of_find_kanjies
    return render_to_response('show_entries.html', {'analyzed_text': analyzed_text, 'list_of_percents': list_of_percents,
                                                 'list_of_find_kanjies': list_of_find_kanjies,})


def send_text(request):
    if 'q' in request.POST:
        q = request.POST['q']
        a = KanjiesText(request.POST['q'])
        a.remove_spaces_from_text()
        list_of_percents = a.take_percent_count()
        list_of_find_kanjies = a.list_find_kanjies()
        for i in range(0,5):
            if len(list_of_find_kanjies[i]) == 0:
                list_of_find_kanjies[i] = ''
        return render_to_response('kanji_analyzer/main.html', {'q': q, 'list_of_percents': list_of_percents,
                                                 'list_of_find_kanjies': list_of_find_kanjies,})
    else:
        q = "your form is empty"
        return render_to_response('kanji_analyzer/main.html', {'q': q},)
```

This block if/else doesn't work. 'q' - value with user's text

Comment: Show us your `views.py`

Comment: In your tag `{% if 'q' != None %}` `q` is a string, not a variable. `{% if q != None %}` would be the correct tag (minus the `'`).

Comment: Also, don't use `global` variables. You can use the [session](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/sessions/) or [cache](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/cache/) if you need to persist variables and information